# Require *.web.js (just like we require *.js files) in javascript codebase

Tags: javascript, webpack

This is available in react-native and allows us to write cross-platform code. I need to use this in one of the existing codebases. Perhaps someone can point me out to a webpack recipe for requiring 'web.js' files; when a 'js' file of the same name is not present. ~ tia

Answer (score 0):

The patch below did it for me. I just have to concat web.js files with rest of the js files.

```
+++ b/webpack/webpack.config.js
@@ -18,19 +18,21 @@ module.exports = (options) => {
       filename: `/scripts/${options.jsFileName}`
     },
     resolve: {
-      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
+      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.web.js']
     },
     module: {
       loaders: [{
-        test: /.js?$/,
+        test: /.js?|.web.js?$/,
```